# Linq projection nested LIST<T> property

Tags: c#, linq

This query has taken a couple days but I am almost there. I have hacked my way through LINQ to entities to come up with the following from reading a lot of tutorials. However this last part I am missing.

I have two basic objects:

```
public class DashboardNavigation()
{
   public int Id {get; set;}
   public string Name {get; set;}
   .....etc.....
   public List<SubNav> SubDashNav {get; set;}
}

public class SubNav()
{
   ....properties....
}




var query = _mlsDashboardNavRepository.Table
        .OrderBy(x => x.Id)
        .Select(x => new
        {
            Id = x.Id,
            Name = x.Name,
            Description = x.Description,
            ImageUrl = x.ImageUrl,
            SubDashNav = _mlsSubDashNav.Table
                .Where(s => s.DashId == x.Id)
                .Select(y => new { Id = y.Id, DashId = y.DashId, Name = y.Name, Description = y.Description, ImageUrl = y.ImageUrl, IsAdvanced = y.IsAdvanced }).ToList()

        }).ToList().Select(q => new MLS_DashboardNavigation()
                            {
                                Id = q.Id,
                                Name = q.Name,
                                Description = q.Description,
                                ImageUrl = q.ImageUrl,
                                SubDashNav = ...???

                            }).ToList();
```

My Linq projects DashboardNavigation correctly but I can't figure out how to get SubDashNav populated???

Comment: What is wrong with `SubDashNav = q.SubDashNav`?

Comment: I thought of that but it still needs some sort of conversion as linq sees it as List<annonymous> but the property is defined List<SubNav> it's that conversion that makes me think I have to project it as well....?

Comment: Erm...get rid of the `.Select` then. There isn't any need for it.

Comment: Well you inspired me to try this SubDashNav = q.SubDashNav.Select(r => new MLS_SubDashNav() {....}).ToList() and it worked perfectly. Are you saying though that it is redundant and really I don't need the SubDash select in the original query?

Comment: In other languages `.Select` is called `.Map`. It is used for transforming objects. In your case, you have a bunch of `SubDashNav`s and you want a bunch of `SubDashNav`s. No transformation necessary.

Comment: Sweet it worked....well I had to add toList() but yeah. Make your comments an answer and I'll gladly accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to select twice. I think this does the same thing.

```
var query = _mlsDashboardNavRepository.Table
    .OrderBy(x => x.Id)
    .Select(x => new MLS_DashboardNavigation()
    {
        Id = x.Id,
        Name = x.Name,
        Description = x.Description,
        ImageUrl = x.ImageUrl,
        SubDashNav = _mlsSubDashNav.Table
            .Where(s => s.DashId == x.Id).ToList()
    }).ToList();
```

And if you are using Entity Framework and navigation properties with DashIs as a foreign key to subNavDash table then you might even be able to do this

```
var query = _mlsDashboardNavRepository.Table
    .OrderBy(x => x.Id)
    .Select(x => new MLS_DashboardNavigation()
    {
        Id = x.Id,
        Name = x.Name,
        Description = x.Description,
        ImageUrl = x.ImageUrl,
        SubDashNav = x.SubDashNav
    }).ToList();
```

And if MLS_DashboardNavigation is the same type as _mlsDashboardNavRepository.Table you won't even need to select as that is whats returned anyway.

```
var query = _mlsDashboardNavRepository.Table
    .OrderBy(x => x.Id).ToList()
```